# Setting a discord bots profile picture

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to set the profile picture of a bots image by doing the code below. Instead of working how I would expect, it results in a message sent with a default avatar for the profile picture instead.

```
chat_message = {
        "username": "planet",
        "avatar":"https://i.imgur.com/kfjHRvR.jpeg",
        "content": "Did the profile picture change?"  
    }
requests.post(DISCORD_URL, json=chat_message)
```

Is there something wrong with the section above? I don't understand why it is not working.

Comment: I'm not really answering your specific question here, but I wanted to point out two things: 1. You can manually change the profile picture of the bot using the web interface (https://discord.com/developers/applications), which is probably easier unless you want to do something fancy with dynamic profile pictures. 2. I would really suggest working with an API library such as [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) which will allow you to use methods and objects to do this kind of stuff, and makes code much easier to write and more readable.

Comment: I will look into those things! Thank you.

Comment: No worries! Do note if you do end up using discord.py specifically I think you'll have to use a beta version to get slash command support (which is how bots integrate directly into the Discord clients, and have the commands pop up when you type '/')